# Reloading UITableView from another class?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, plist, protocols, reloaddata

This is a question rather many people have asked, especially here on StackOverflow.

Reloading the data on the table view is easy, `[self.myTableView reloadData];`, myTableView is the instance of my UITableView, since I am using a UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController.

I want to reload the table view from another view controller after I have updated the data (from Internet). The data is contained in a property list. I have tried using protocols, notifications and some other things like putting it in `viewDidAppear:`. Nothing have worked for me.

Is it something I haven't thought about or have I just done some of the methods wrong? The help is much appreciated!

Comment: Okay, worked it out by myself, finally!

Comment: What was it that solved the problem?

Comment: The fact that I had the data in property lists. I just used the code for initializing the data into the table view to load it again, when I wanted. It became a "reload".

Answer (score 0):

If you want access to a UITableView object, or just about anything else for that matter, from another class, you can make it accessible  using a property:

**ClassA.h**

```
@interface ClassA {
    UITableView *tableView;
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

**ClassB.m**

```
- (void)reloadTableInOtherClass {
    [classAVariable.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using observer pattern + notification is a good way. And to let your view controller decide when to reload data is also a good practice.
Why notification does not work. Did you use addOvserver: ?